# IIS 6.0 new server

Tags: iis

I have a server that is going buggy, so we built a new server to replace it.  Now I am tasked with moving all of the sites in iis to the new server.  I thought there was a way to export all the settings and I tried using the export and import option - but the sites do not exist on the new server - I assume I am using the command incorrectly?

Can someone help me with the right command to basically copy all of the sites in iis onto another server?

This is what I tried: 
iiscnfg /export /f d:\temp\config.xml /sp /lm/w3svc /children /inherited /d password

I copied the config.xml to the new server and the did: 
iiscnfg /import /f d:\temp\config.xml /sp /lm/w3svc /dp /lm/w3svc /merge /d password

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You'll probably have more luck on serverfault.com - voting to move your question there.

Comment: This is a superuser or serverfault.com question not stackoverflow.  We try to specialize in programming questions not server related.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [MSDeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) for this task.  It is available free from Microsoft, and can synch up two servers, as well as help migrate from IIS6 to IIS7.